# How to unlock a plant, animal or mineral

Tags: reus

When hovering over the next upgrade for a resource it says: 
"This animal is still locked! Try to develop humans differently to unlock it."

What are you suppose to do to unlock the next tier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the official wiki:

> Work towards achievements; they unlock new plants/animals/projects, which in turn lead to better resources!

Doing enough achievements/developments will unlock the next tier.

Source: http://wiki.reusgame.com/index.php?title=Walkthrough
Under Beginner tips.